# Adding element to the list on keypress and clearing the list

Tags: javascript, html

As in topic my job is to do a code where user writes some text into textbox and when user hits enter key,  the text from the textbox should be added to ul list under Things header.
I added also reset button but it's not working because adding elements to list isn't working but I think it should work when I will fix it. I don't know where I made mistake. Could anyone help me or give me advice what should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">List</h1>

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="user-todo" placeholder="List" required>
    </form>

    <h2 id="todo-header">Things</h2>
    <ul id="list">

    </ul>
    <button id="clear">Reset</button>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById("user-todo");
        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // what happens when user hits ENTER
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('ul').append("<li>"+($('#user-todo').val()) + "</li>");
                });
            }
        });

        function clear() {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors reported in your console? If so, what are they? You haven't tagged your question with jQuery, you haven't included the jQuery library and yet you seem to be *trying* to use jQuery. I'd imagine that's the problem, but without more details I can't be sure.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery and I shouldn't. I can only use JavaScript. Console gives me no errors.

Comment: So why is it in there if you can't use it?

Comment: I didn't know that I'm using it. I'm just a beginner in programming and I'm learning JavaScript. I tried using some other code from the web and that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: it is ok that you are beginner and we are here to help you, but we are not guesser to guess what you want to do. So what make it doesn't work or make you ask question here?

Comment: You're listening `keyup`, its default action is not to submit the form, hence preventing the default action doesn't have any effect, the form is submitted. You've to listen `submit` event of the form, and prevent its default action.

Comment: <body><input type="text" id="user-todo" placeholder="List" required></form><ul id="list"></ul><button id="clear" onclick="clear()">Reset</button><script>var list = document.getElementById('list');var input = document.getElementById("user-todo");input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {if (event.keyCode === 13) {
var create = document.createElement('li');
var content = document.createTextNode(input.value);
create.appendChild(content);
list.appendChild(create);console.log(input.value);}
        });function clear() {
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '';}</script>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on an outdated course, you can learn Modern JS at:

https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/

https://phoenix35.js.org/

Dispensing the use of JQuery, a framework that is no longer necessary these days, you get:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#user-todo");
const clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
const list = document.querySelector("#list");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = input.value;

        input.value = "";

        list.appendChild(li);
    }
});

clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
    list.innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">List</h1>

        <form onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="text" id="user-todo" placeholder="List" required> 
        </form>

        <h2 id="todo-header">Things</h2>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
        <button id="clear">Reset</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: preventDefault will not stop the form from being submitted, so add the onsubmit attribute to the tag with the string "return false;" e.g: <form onsubmit="return false;">

Answer (score 0):

If you change this line, it should work.
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sinoussi-ckw8b?file=/index.html

```
 input.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
```

Comment: @Toby Don't be so unkind. You should at least test the code before posting such comments.

Comment: no explaination, nothing. How is that a good answer? I am sorry for such rood comment, and I hope this comment will teach you a lesson.

Comment: Unlike you, I tried to provide a possible working solution.

Comment: ok, you're so amazing! I'm just trying to tell you that you should expand your answer a bit so that the questioner can learn from their mistake. If you want, you should search for "How do I ask a good qeustion?".

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="title">List</h1>


    <input type="text" id="user-todo" placeholder="List" required>

    <h2 id="todo-header">Things</h2>
    <ul id="list">

    </ul>
    <button onclick="clearFunction()">Reset</button>
    <script>

        function clearFunction() {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = " ";
        }
        var input = document.getElementById("user-todo")
        var list = document.getElementById("list");

        input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var input_val = document.getElementById("user-todo").value;
                let li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerText = input_val;
                list.append(li);
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="title">List</h1>

    <form onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="text" id="user-todo" placeholder="List" required>
    </form>

    <h2 id="todo-header">Things</h2>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
    <button id="clear">Reset</button>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById("user-todo");
        var list = document.getElementById("list");
        var reset = document.getElementById("clear");
        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            console.log('keyCode is ' + event.keyCode);
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                var item = document.createElement('LI');
                item.innerHTML = input.value;
                list.appendChild(item);
            }
        });
        reset.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            list.innerHTML = '';
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```